# Swift used for research

Tags: swift, macos, swift-playground, robotics

I am currently considering using Swift for my academic projects (I saw that it is faster than Python, so want to give it a go). Going through the possibilities I was wondering how should I approach the problem.

**My question list**

- Should I use playgrounds for the project I want? This isn't really an app, just some math algorithms, that I would want to run on the laboratory robots.
- I would want to create a library from the project for further use by other scientists through for eg. Carthage. How could I achieve that?
- Can Swift be used out of the box, the way I want (let's say console), or I really need to create a MacOS app for it to be run and transfer the data to the robot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift is a general-purpose, multi-paradigm, compiled programming language developed by Apple Inc. for iOS, macOS, watchOS, tvOS, and Linux. Swift is designed to work with Apple's Cocoa and Cocoa Touch frameworks and the large body of extant Objective-C (ObjC) code written for Apple products.

For more reference go through: [SWIFT](https://swift.org/getting-started/#using-the-package-manager)

Yes, You can experiment with Swift code in "Playgrounds."One of Swift's most interesting features and interactive environment is Playground. This tool lets you see the effects of changes or additions to code as you type, without going through the time-consuming rigmarole of running the code through the compiler and executing it.

Other Playground features include the capability to "watch" the value of a variable, typing its name on a separate line in the code and seeing its current value displayed in a side bar, as well as a set of "Quick Look" buttons that display images, strings and other content intended for graphical display.

Comment: This doesn't answer all my questions. Will I be able to create a library (framework) out of the Swift code I write in Playgrounds? And what is the possibility of working in Playgrounds with Carthage.

Comment: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/using-third-party-framework-in-playground-with-carthage-82ead87a5bd7#.81kb894ce

Comment: Thank you for all the replies!